# Load page in customizer preview on panel click?

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer

I'm trying to extend customizer with some functionality but documentation is lacking for cases that are non-control related.

E.g. I’d like to load some url in preview after clicking the panel.

My two issues are:

1. I can’t attach events to panels and fields because regular click and change don’t work because panels seem to be loaded not immediately.
2. How would one then send a custom message to preview section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've documented how to do this in my post [Navigating to a URL in the Customizer Preview when a Section is Expanded](https://make.xwp.co/2016/07/21/navigating-to-a-url-in-the-customizer-preview-when-a-section-is-expanded/), though naturally you'd just use panels instead of sections.

This should get you what you want:

```
(function ( api ) {
    api.panel( 'my_panel_id', function( panel ) {
        panel.expanded.bind( function( isExpanded ) {
            if ( isExpanded ) {
                api.previewer.previewUrl.set( panelPreviewUrl );
            }
        } );
    } );
} ( wp.customize ) );
```

You'd replace the `panelPreviewUrl` variable with whatever you want to navigate the preview to. And then you'd replace `'my_panel_id'` with whatever the ID is for your panel.

Comment: Thanks. What if I wanted to manipulate panels in another way, e.g. clone them? Is it possible to obtain panel as a DOM node ./ jQuery object?

Comment: No, do not clone with jQuery. You have to use the `wp.customize` API to create new panels. You should ask a new question about doing that.